# Q_ASSERT Issues when porting projet from Qt 5.15.2 to Qt 6.5.2

Tags: qt

I am quite new to Qt environment and I'm currently trying to port a project from Qt 5.15.2 to Qt 6.5.2.
When I am building this project on Qt 6.5.2, I'm getting more than 22000 errors relied to qassert.h:30 and here are the content of the errors :

```
C:\Qt\6.5.2\mingw_64\include\QtCore\qassert.h:30: error: there are no arguments to 'qt_assert' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'qt_assert' must be available [-fpermissive]
In file included from C:/Qt/6.5.2/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:36,
from C:/Qt/6.5.2/mingw_64/include/QtCore/QtGlobal:1,
from D:\Git\mesure\src\qxtglobal.h:35,
from D:\Git\mesure\src\qxtglobal.cpp:32:
C:/Qt/6.5.2/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qminmax.h: In function 'constexpr const T& qBound(const T&, const T&, const T&)':
C:/Qt/6.5.2/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qassert.h:30:61: error: there are no arguments to 'qt_assert' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'qt_assert' must be available [-fpermissive]
30 | #    define Q_ASSERT(cond) ((cond) ? static_cast<void>(0) : qt_assert(#cond, __FILE__, __LINE__))
   |                                                             ^~~~~~~~~
C:/Qt/6.5.2/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qminmax.h:46:5: note: in expansion of macro 'Q_ASSERT'
46 |     Q_ASSERT(!(max < min));
   |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/Qt/6.5.2/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qassert.h:30:61: note: (if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
30 | #    define Q_ASSERT(cond) ((cond) ? static_cast<void>(0) : qt_assert(#cond, __FILE__, __LINE__))
   |                                                             ^~~~~~~~~
C:/Qt/6.5.2/mingw_64/include/QtCore/qminmax.h:46:5: note: in expansion of macro 'Q_ASSERT'
46 |     Q_ASSERT(!(max < min));
   |     ^~~~~~~~
```

And here is the code error in qassert.h :

```
Q_CORE_EXPORT void qt_assert(const char *assertion, const char *file, int line) noexcept;


#if defined(QT_NO_DEBUG) && !defined(QT_FORCE_ASSERTS)
#define Q_ASSERT(cond) static_cast<void>(false && (cond))
#else
#define Q_ASSERT(cond) ((cond) ? static_cast<void>(0) : qt_assert(#cond, __FILE__, __LINE__))
#endif
```

I don't know what to do to resolve this issue.

Comment: What gcc version do you use? Make sure to use the ones which are supported by Qt: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/supported-platforms.html